Spring Integration Java DSL TCP outbound and Inbound Connection Handler
I need to create a dynamic TCP outbound adapter that acts as a client, connects to a server, and handles the server's response. While the request is being sent to the server correctly, I am unable to receive the server's response. I have verified using Wireshark that the server is indeed sending a response, but my code does not seem to capture it. Please review my code and let me know what might be wrong.
  TcpNetClientConnectionFactory cf = new TcpNetClientConnectionFactory(ip, port);
        cf.setDeserializer(new CustomDeserializer());


        IntegrationFlow out = IntegrationFlow.from("clientInputChannel")
                .handle(Tcp.outboundAdapter(cf))
                .transform(Transformers.objectToString())
                .get();


        this.flowContext.registration(out)
                .addBean(cf)
                .id(port + ".out")
                .register();

        IntegrationFlow in = IntegrationFlow.from(Tcp.inboundAdapter(cf)).channel("fromTcp").get();

        this.flowContext.registration(in)
                .id(port + ".in")
                .register();


        IntegrationFlow responseFlow = IntegrationFlow.from("fromTcp")
                .handle(message -> {
                    log.info("UGV Response " + message.getPayload());
                })
                .get();

        this.flowContext.registration(responseFlow)
                .id("errorFlow")
                .register();

Following are my Message Channels
    @Bean("clientInputChannel")
    public MessageChannel clientInputChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean("fromTcp")
    public QueueChannel fromTcp() {
        return new QueueChannel();
    }

This is how i am sending message to server
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("clientInputChannel")
    private MessageChannel toTcp;

    @Override
    public boolean sendHex(byte[] buffer) {
       log.info("Sending Bytes: " + buffer);
        toTcp.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(buffer).build());
       log.info("Bytes Sent");
       return true;
    }



I have also added ServiceActivator to test but none is working
  @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "fromTcp")
    public void receiver(PelcoResponseMessage in) {
        System.out.println("Received " + in + " from ");
    }


    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "fromTcp")
    public void receiver1(byte[] in) {
        System.out.println("Received1 " + in + " from ");
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "fromTcp")
    public void receiver2(String in) {
        System.out.println("Received2 " + in + " from ");
    }


@artem-bilan can you please advice

You need to be sure that your CustomDeserializer parses properly packaged from the server. In most cases it is a delimiter problem to distinguish one message from another: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/ip/tcp-connection-factories.html#tcp-codecs.
If you say that server accepts your requests, then apparently it relies on the default serialization strategy - ByteArrayCrLfSerializer. So, see what is that delimiter for replies to utilize in your CustomDeserializer.
